# Can't take heap snapshot with chrome inspector for nodejs

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, heap-memory, remote-debugging, portforwarding

I run my nodejs 8.9.4 app (which is not a server) in a remote Kubernetes cluster with `node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 app.js`. I then port-forward 9229 on my machine. Finally, I access to chrome inspector and I can see my source code. I tried to run with `--inspect-brk` and I successfuly debugged my app. But I can't take heap snapshot: the button is disabled. I can't understand why.
[Disabled take snapshot button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtfVk.png)

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to :

1. Update chrome to latest version and relaunched it (also it is good to download  [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) )
2. Restart node
3. Open chrome://inspect and added localhost: port number -9229  [update connection in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX65o.png).

Take a look: [debugging-nodejs](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27), [memory-leaks-nodejs](https://marmelab.com/blog/2018/04/03/how-to-track-and-fix-memory-leak-with-nodejs.html).

Comment: Thanks. I finally upgrade my nodes version to 10, then now I can take snapshot with the same Chrome version and same process.

Comment: @Antoine so you were not able to do this with the older version of Node? I also am on Node 8.9.4 and cannot seem to do remote debugging.

Comment: No sorry, I had to upgrade my node version.